# Called from Sanic functions throws "asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop"

Tags: python, python-asyncio, sanic, sanic-openapi

I'm new to asyncio. Tried to create an async decorator with that for blocking I/O code.

```
def singletonAsyncMaker(func):
    async def inner(obj, ):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        tasks = (loop.run_in_executor(None, func, i) for i in obj)
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    def main(obj):
        return asyncio.run(inner(obj))

    return main

@singletonAsyncMaker
def sleeper(obj):
    sleep(2)
    return obj

x = sleeper([8, 5, 6, 6, 4645, 63, 4, 6, 1, 64, 614, 24, 65, ])
print(x)
```

This worked well normally and also within normal non-async functions, but when called through a route function of a Sanic server it throws this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app.py", line 99, in extractImageResponse
    result = perform_textract_bytestream(images)
  File "async_experiment.py", line 51, in main
    return asyncio.run(inner(obj))
  File "env/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 33, in run
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
```

```
@app.route("/v0/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", methods=['POST'])
def function_name(request):
    -----------------
    x = sleeper(list)
    -----------------
    return jsonify(json_op)
```

Tried adding **async** to sanic `function_name` definition and **await** before `sleeper()` call to no luck.
I know that sanic works with asyncio, does that contibute to this?
Any fix or work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to call `asyncio.run` inside Sanic.

```py
@app.route("/v0/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", methods=['POST'])
async def function_name(request):
    await call_to_some_coroutine()
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. Is there a way to identify if the request is coming from Sanic? like knowing there's another thread going on? Want to use the same for both Sanic function calls and regular calls

Comment: You could pass the request object as an optional argument..